# How can I use input arguments when using optimization tool?

Tags: matlab, optimization

main.m

```
...
param = ...;
x0 = [0,0];
[newX, fval] = fminimax(@myfun, x0)
...
```

myfun.m

```
function f = myfun(x)
  f(1)=function of (x, param);
  f(2)=another function of (x, param);
  f(3)=...
  ...
  f(5)=the last function of (x, param);
end
```

How can I pass the parameter 'param' to myfun file?

---

I tried to like the following, but error occurs.

```
...
param = ...;
x0 = [0,0];
[newX, fval] = fminimax(@myfun, x0, param)
...
```

and

```
function f = myfun(x, param)
  f(1)=function of (x, param);
  f(2)=another function of (x, param);
  f(3)=...
  ...
  f(5)=the last function of (x, param);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in main you want to make new function. Like this:

```
param = ...;
myfuncinclparam = @(x0)myfun(x0,param)
x0 = [0,0];
[newX, fval] = fminimax(@myfuncinclparam, x0)
```

for futher reference please check:
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html#bvadxhn-9